# Issues with Sub Reports in Crystal Reports Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, windows, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-viewer

I have developed an windows application, in which I'm using Crystal Reports to generate reports. Added some sub reports in it and it's working all fine. I have added a new report and a sub report in it, The new report is not working and causing the specific error attached in screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot attached]

I have observed in the temp folder, while generating this report, The following file is created and for my other reports no such files are created. Attached the screenshot of that also for your reference. And this file causes the issue.

[image]

Can anyone help on this as I have surfed all possible solutions and anything didn't help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After a long struggle., Added a sub report using wizard instead of pointing to an existing  sub report. Still not clear why that issue happened. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

What version of the Crystal runtime? RDC?
Does your report use dynamic parameters?
Does the problem go away if you change them to static parameters?

Comment: Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2008. Yes it has parameters. Without parameter the result is same. The error comes when it logon for sub report added is failed.


`foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in subreport.Database.Tables)
                    {
                        crTableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                        crTableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogoninfo);
                    }`